# Is there a better/more efficient way to generate a multi-criteria filter for a specific column/s in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the following function to automatically create a filter for a given dataframe. My goal was to take a dataframe, a given column, and the cell values I want to include, and have the function return a filter of boolean values that I can then apply.

```
def filter_df(df, column, filter_list: list): 
'''returns boolean Series that can be used as a 
   filter of the base dataframe'''

   criteria = []
   count = 0
   for i in filter_list:
       single_crit = df[column] == i
       if count == 0:
           criteria = single_crit
           count += 1
           continue
       criteria = list(np.logical_or(criteria, single_crit))
   return criteria
```

Input:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'jon', 'steve', 'laura', 
                'alison', 'rachel'], 
        'Age':[20, 21, 20, 18, 21, 23, 24, 18, 20]}
df_names = pd.DataFrame(data)
filter_criteria = [20, 21]
age_filter = filter_df(df_names, 'Age', filter_criteria)
```

Output: age_filter
   [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, True]

To me, I would have expected something like this to come as part of the package. I'm mostly seeking advice on ways to simplify this function.

Comment: Look like `return df[column].isin(filter_list).to_list()` is all you need

Comment: Thanks @CodeDifferent! That looks like it does exactly what I was hoping to find. What is it called when there are functions applied using the period like you've done?